# Django CreateView: How to create the resource before rendering the form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model class for my resource,

```
class Article(db.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255, blank=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from='title')
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
```

Here's my form class

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = kb_models.Article
```

And finally my CreateView,

```
class CreateArticleView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = ArticleForm
    model = Article

    def get_success_url(self):
       return "some_redirect_url"
```

Right now I have configured my URLs like below,

```
path('add/', CreateArticleView.as_view(), name='create_article')
path('<slug:article>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
path('<slug:article>/update', UpdateArticleView.as_view(), name='update_article')
```

The current flow will render a form when I hit the `add/` resource endpoint, and save the resource in the database only after I submit the form. After that, the article can be accessed using the slug generated from the title.

What I want instead is to be able to create the Article resource before the resource is rendered, so that the `add/` endpoint redirects to some `add/unique-uuid` endpoint, and even when the form is not submitted from the browser, this empty resource is preserved, and it can be accessed later on because of the `unique-uuid`.

I thought of instantiating an object and redirecting that to UpdateView, but I am having difficulties in figuring out how to keep track of the `unique-uuid` and point both generated-uuid and slug to the same resource. Additionally, this seems like a common use-case, so I'm wondering if there's a better standard way to do this.

Comment: But wouldn't that result in a lot of (perhaps) inconsistent objects. Imagine that one adds an `Article`, starts writing one, and then stops, or submits the form, and the content is invalid. It will also generate a lot of "weakly checked" values: for example if your `Article` needs a `Collection`, then that is later added, so then `collection` should be `NULL`able, only for a "temporary" record.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I agree with you. The problem that I have presently is the Articles are very long to write and if the user closes the browser tab accidentally or forgets to submit, all his progress is lost.

Comment: I think the functionality that I need is similar to that of sites like Medium, but I'm struggling to find how that can be implemented with Django. I know there will be some AJAX involved, but I'm far from figuring out an efficient way to achieve that.